# Implementation of user login via REST api (fosuserbundle)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an angularJS application that communicates with a Symfony2 REST server

both of the app & server is under my responsibility I am wondering how to login a specific user using the FOSUserBundle.

I thought about the following scenario:

1. Login action that will get `username` & `password` from the AngularJS application and will return to it some kind of an `access_token` string that will have a timeout of let's say 12 hours.
2. after reciving the access_token the angularJS application will use it in every single request to identify the user.

Now I wonder if this is how I should do this kind of authentication
and also how could I implement it using FOSUserBundle in Symfony2? what would be the "BEST Practice"?

Answer (score 0):

For future people that ends here googling , check :

https://gist.github.com/tjamps/11d617a4b318d65ca583

that's the way to go .

**Basic RESTful API with Symfony 2 + FOSRestBundle (JSON format only) + FOSUserBundle + FOSOauthServerBundle**

The API we are creating in this gist will follow these rules :

- The API only returns JSON responses
- All API routes require authentication
- Authentication is handled via OAuth2 with password
  Grant Type only (no need for Authorization pages and such).
- API
  versioning is managed via a subdomain (e.g. v1.api.example.com)